# Do while loop runs more than once with flag set?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am having trouble getting this loop to only run once. I have a flag set and my understanding is it will run through once, change `flag = 1`, then not run through again but when I execute it, the loop runs over and over again. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The issue I'm finding is even when my voltage satisfies the if statement, the loop continues to run.

```
voltage = analogRead(A0); //reads in voltage from pin A0
Serial.println(voltage);

//Calibration routine
do {
  if ((voltage >= 1) && (voltage <= 10)) {
    //while the voltage is between 4.88 and 48.8 mV the calibration light will flash once
    //this ensures the voltage is above 0 and lower than the threshold for the max voltage routine
    digitalWrite(calibrationLED, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(calibrationLED, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(calibrationLED, HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    Serial.println("Calibrated");
    delay(5000);
    voltageInitial = analogRead(A0);
    //stores the initial voltage to a separate variable, does not change over the course of the crimp
    Serial.println("Initial Voltage: ");
    Serial.println(voltageInitial);
    flag = 1;
  }
} while (flag == 0);
```

Comment: Is the condition met? Where is the variable `flag` declared?

Comment: You prnt out the voltage before the loop, (Serial.println(voltage);).  What is it?  Why do you not tell us this important info?

Comment: Did you not notice the execution jumping over the if block when you stepped through with your debugger?

Comment: There is no need for any loop in your case!

Comment: @ThingyWotsit there is no debugger on an Arduino.

Comment: @gre_gor Ewww... send it back.  It is not useable.

Answer (score 5):

The `flag` variable will only get set to 1 if the `if` condition is true.  This happens when `voltage` has a value from 1 to 10.

If the value of `voltage` is not in the range 1 - 10, `flag` will not be set.  And since `voltage` is never modified inside of the loop, you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

"the loop runs over and over again. "
It smells the loop never enter inside `if ((voltage >= 1) && (voltage <= 10))` ,
thus never set `flag = 1`;

So naturally it keep running.

Answer (score 2):

This is an infinite loop actually until the value of the voltage comes between 1 to 10. so `flag=1` should be out of the if condition. Otherwise you can add a `break` after if condition is finished. It will execute exactly once after the condition.

Comment: Anyways you need the loop only if you are planning to wait for voltage to lie in between 1 to 10. Otherwise loop is not at all needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are waiting for the `voltage` variable to change, without actually changing it (reading from analog pin).

You need to add `voltage = analogRead(A0);` into your loop.

```
do
{
    voltage = analogRead(A0);
    if ((voltage >= 1) && (voltage <= 10))   //while the voltage is between 4.88 and 48.8 mV the calibration light will flash once
    {                                        //this ensures the voltage is above 0 and lower than the threshold for the max voltage routine 
        ...

        flag = 1;
    }
} while (flag == 0);
```